# PGFPlots show full decimal numbers on nodes and ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, graphs

I have following graph

[image]

and i need written out decimal numbers on the y ticks axis aswell as ontop of the bars. I found some other questions here that said to use `y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}`, which did absolutely nothing for me, and `scaled ticks=false`, which kind of worked for the axis but made some weird things aswell and didnt work for the bars.

[image]

Is there a reliable way for me to just completly write out the numbers (0.0051 and 0.018) on the axis AND the nodes?

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %
\usepackage{pgfplots} %
\begin{document}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \pgfplotsset{width=9 cm, height=9cm}
                    \begin{axis} [
                        symbolic x coords={0, last year, this year},
                        xtick={last year, this year},
%                        scaled ticks=false,
                        axis lines*=left, 
                        ymajorgrids = true, %shows the y grid
                        ymin=0,
%                        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
                        bar width=12.5mm,
                        ybar=-1cm, 
                        enlarge x limits={abs=2.33cm},
                        nodes near coords,
                        every node near coord/.append style={color=black},
                    ]
                        \addplot [Red,fill=Red]
                        coordinates{ (last year,0.0051) (this year,0.018) } ;
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the number format for both axes and bars, we can use

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=4}
```

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %
\usepackage{pgfplots} %
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%<-- added
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{width=9 cm, height=9cm}
  \pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=4,
  }%<-- this line
  \begin{axis} [
      symbolic x coords={0, last year, this year},
      xtick={last year, this year},
      scaled ticks=false,
      axis lines*=left,
      ymajorgrids = true, %shows the y grid
      ymin=0,
      %  y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=4},
      bar width=12.5mm,
      ybar=-1cm,
      enlarge x limits={abs=2.33cm},
      nodes near coords,
      every node near coord/.append style={color=black},
    ]
    \addplot [Red,fill=Red]
    coordinates{ (last year,0.0051) (this year,0.018) } ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works great, thank you alot!